# jquery data table is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am working with a table and I find a lot of problems using a table. Then I found jquery data table, but I don't understand why its not working. I added all the links from the data table website.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>data table</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<th>Company</th>
<th>Contact</th>
<th>Country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
<td>Maria Anders</td>
<td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
<td>Francisco Chang</td>
<td>Mexico</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ernst Handel</td>
<td>Roland Mendel</td>
<td>Austria</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Island Trading</td>
<td>Helen Bennett</td>
<td>UK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
<td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
<td>Canada</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
<td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
<td>Italy</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

My javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Because it is not working, I downloaded the data table as a zip file.

The add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dataTables.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

But it is still not working.

Comment: Put your jquery link ahead of the other <script> tags

Comment: make sure jquery src is `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"` if you are not running in local server

Answer (score 1):

You have to call **Jquery** before **datatable** :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dataTables.js'></script>
```

You dont need to call the `datatable.js` **and** the `.min.js`, just choose one.

then use this for jquery : `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134514/discussion-between-nayan-chowdhury-and-singe-batteur).

Comment: i add http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js but not working